# Spark simple query with cached table takes longer than not cached

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, parquet

I have a simple query, I've tested it without caching the table and then by caching the table. The cached version takes 2 mins while the uncached takes 20 seconds.

I noticed the cached version does read from Memory, but it does this `ColumnartoRow` operation followed by a `RowToColumnar` operation (which doesn't makes sense to me) that the non-cached version did not used. The bottlenecks of the process are those two operation. If it wouldn't be for them, the query would be faster than the non-cached version.

This is my simple query for didactic purposes:
`SELECT user_id,count(*) FROM transaction  GROUP BY 1`

I first ran it "raw" without running anything before. And then I tried caching the table with

```
%sql
CACHE TABLE transaction OPTIONS ('storageLevel' 'MEMORY_AND_DISK') as SELECT * FROM transaction
```

And ran the same query again.

I understand from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792152/how-is-columnartorow-an-efficient-operation-in-spark) that the `ColumnarToRow` happens because since my file is parquet (columnar) but spark's RDDs (at least up to version 2.0) are Row-based then it has to apply that conversion. But I am not sure of that, as I rarely see that operation during the processing even though most all of my tables are in parquets. Even so, what's the point of doing `ColumnarToRow` followed by `RowtoColumar` ?

This first picture is my query plan of the non cached version. And the last picture is of the cached version.

[image: Not Cached]

And here is the picture of the cached version

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure so take my answer with the necessary grain of salt, but I still this might provide some info that might help you.

You're using Databricks' [Photon Runtime](https://docs.databricks.com/runtime/photon.html), which is not open source (hence why I'm not sure, can't have a look at the code) and I haven't used it before.

But after reading some pages like the one above and [this one](https://blog.the-pans.com/photon/), it seems like one of the big performance benefits should be due to vectorized calculations. From the second page:

> Databricks wrote Photon in C++ because the workload is becoming more CPU bound. C++ has a few advantages when it comes to optimizing the efficiency of in-memory workloads:
>
> - more explicit control over memory pipelining and SIMD instructions
> - no garbage collection.

> Photon operates against a batched columnar data layout.
>
> For each column vector, there is a buffer of values and a byte vector holding the NULL-ness of each value. Position list stores indices of rows in the batch that are "active"...

So it seems to me that the basic object underlying Datasets (RDDs) are completely overhauled in Photon. RDDs are row based, which means that if you read a columnar file (like parquet) you would need a `ColumnarToRow` step in your physical plan before creating an RDD. It seems like with Photon, the need of this is removed (I learnt something new here, thanks!). I'm not sure to which extent this is though.

**But why did the addition of a `.cache` operation add the need of adding both a `ColumnarToRow` step and a `PhotonRowToColumnar` step in your physical plan?**

My guess (it is a guess!) would be that the underlying code is still using vanilla Spark's `.cache` method, which is based on RDDs and hence needs to convert your data from Columnar data to Row data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try without photon in a second and see what it does

Comment: It was faster and it seems this theory could be right. I've added the results in the next answer

Answer (score 0):

In response to @Koedlt answer. I tried on a cluster without photon and the theory seems to fit. In non-photon runtime it did not applied the RowtoColumnar.

So It's feasible to say (but not confirmed) that photon operates on Columnar data. So it needs to get data in Columnar format to work

On the other hand, spark works with RDDs which are Row data. So it needs row data.

Therefore, if information is stored in parquets (columnar). Photon seems to be fine with that, and Sparks needs to do a first task of ColumnarToRow to work with that. Which is true if I try the same query in a non-photon environment.

On the other hand, when we use photon, one would think that since the parquet is columnar then photon does not needs any transformation if it reads directly from the parquet. And this is true. In the question I attached the plan of Not-cached table we do not see any ColumnarToRow transformation.

Nevertheless, when I cache my table, spark caches it as an RDD (I guess), so it already cached it on Row format despite the parquets where in columnar format. That's because it seems it is the RDD that gets cached, not the parquets. So if photon uses a cached table it receives a spark RDD on Row format, and so it needs to apply a ColumnartoRow step because photon uses Columnar data.

This might explain why:

1. Photon reading straight from in-disk parquet has neither ColumnarToRow nor RowtoColumnar transformations. Because parquets are already columnar and photon works with columnar
2. Photon reading from a spark cached table (RDD) needs to do a RowToColumnar transformation to the cached RDD, because the RDD is in Row format since Spark converted the parquets to cached RDD using a ColumnarToRow. Therefore, photon reading from cache we can see the ColumnarToRow that spark did to cache the parquets followed by a RowToColumnar done by photon to read the cached RDD
3. Spark reading from a on-disk parquet always needs to do a ColumnarToRow to transform the parquet into RDDs so it can operate with it.

Here is the execution plans of cached and non cached using only vanilla spark without photon.

My results are:

1. Vanilla spark - non cached table: 33 seconds
2. Vanilla spark -cached table: 5 seconds
3. Photon - non cached table : 2 seconds
4. Photon - cached table: 14 seconds

#3 being the fastest can make sense because photon is fine with the columnar format of parquets, and thus it does not needs to do any ColumnarToRow transformation that spark does. Also it has some optimizations. It's interesting to see that even though it reads from disk, it outperformed #2 that is on RAM. Maybe this is because photon is more optimized and columnar data fits well on it, even if it has to read it from disk. But I guess this can change depending on the data on every case

It would be very nice if Photon could also cache in Columnar form. Because if this whole theory its true, it looks like it might be a bad thing to cache tables if we are using Photon?

Here is vanilla spark plan with not cached table
[image: Spark not cached]

And here is vanilla spark plan with cached table
[image: Spark cached table]

Comment: Ahhh that's very interesting information. Learnt something new with this question! Thanks :)