different physical plan between pyspark and scala spark
I'd like to kwnow why there is differents physical plans between this pyspark code :
transactions_file = "../data/data_skew/transactions.parquet"
df_transactions = spark.read.parquet(transactions_file)
df_narrow_transform = (
df_customers
    .filter(F.col("city") == "boston")
    .withColumn("first_name", F.split("name", " ").getItem(0))
    .withColumn("last_name", F.split("name", " ").getItem(1))
    .withColumn("age", F.col("age") + F.lit(5))
    .select("cust_id", "first_name", "last_name", "age", "gender", "birthday")
)
df_narrow_transform.explain(True)

I have this Physical plan
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project ....
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(city#73) AND (city#73 = boston))
+- *(1) ColumnarToRow
  +- FileScan parquet ....

And this scala code :
val transactions_file = "../data/data_skew/customers.parquet"
val df_customers = sparkSession.read.parquet(transactions_file)
df_customers.show(false)

val df_narrow_transform = (
  df_customers
    .filter($"city" === "boston")
    .withColumn("first_name", split($"name", " ")(0))
    .withColumn("last_name", split($"name", " ")(1))
    .withColumn("age", col("age") + lit(5))
    .select("cust_id", "first_name", "last_name", "age", "gender", "birthday")
  )

df_narrow_transform.explain(true)

I have this physical plan
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project ...
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(city#6) && (city#6 = boston))
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet ...

Why in pyspark there is an extra ColumnarToRow
Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055083/3238085 , Looks like ColumnarToRow is python to scala specific transformation. https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/what-is-the-quot-columnar-to-row-quot-node-in-this-simple/td-p/48888

@user238607 - you should put this as the answer
